# Center of a split unipotent group

Tags: gr.group-theory, algebraic-groups

Let $N$ be a unipotent algebraic group over a field $k$ of characteristic $p>0$.
Assume that $N$ is split (i.e. it admits a filtration whose quotients are isomorphic to the additive group).
In particular, it is smooth and connected (since the additive group is smooth and connected and these two properties are stable under passing to extensions).

Then which of the following subgroups of $N$ are split?

- the (scheme-theoretic) center of $N$ (or its identity component)

  the maximal smooth central $k$-subgroup of $N$ (or its identity component)

  the cc$kp$-kernel of $N$ (i.e. the maximal smooth connected central $p$-torsion $k$-subgroup of $N$)

Comment: Your definition of "split" only makes sense for smooth connected unipotent groups, but there is a more general notion of unipotent group scheme (see section 1 of Expose XVII of SGA3). So probably you are assuming $N$ is smooth and connected, but its scheme-theoretic center is often neither smooth nor connected, so what exactly do you mean by $Z_N$? It will help to clarify what is your motivation.  Would it be sufficient for your purposes (whatever they may be) to show that if $N$ is split and non-trivial then it admits $\mathbf{G}_{\rm{a}}$ as a central $k$-subgroup? (That does always hold.)

Comment: Or maybe you just want that (when $N$ is split smooth connected unipotent and non-trivial) that there is a non-trivial split central smooth connected $k$-subgroup that is stable under all $k_s$-automorphisms of $N_{k_s}$?

Comment: I think the definition of "split" makes sense for any unipotent group scheme, but indeed a split unipotent group is automatically smooth and connected (since these two properties hold true for the additive group and are stable under passing to extensions). As for my motivation it is indeed the following: any split unipotent group admits a (finite) series of characteristic split subgroups whose quotients are direct products of copies of the additive group.

Comment: (I can prove the result I need using the split part of the cckp-kernel, from Tits' Lecture on algebraic groups, but I came to think about this simple question on the center of split unipotent groups which I find interesting on its own.)

Comment: In the analogous case with tori, one has the wider notion of "group scheme of multiplicative type" and a notion of "split" for that which doesn't imply "smooth + connected". That's why I was asking if you had a definition of "split" for unipotent group schemes which can hold without implying "smooth+connected". And the reason I asked that was because if not and if $Z_N$ isn't smooth and connected then one would have a counterexample. So I ask again: what does "center" mean?  Is it the scheme-theoretic center, or the maximal smooth central $k$-subgroup, or the identity component of that, or...?

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. You're right, the "center" is ambiguous here. Actually I would be interested in the answer for each case. I'll edit the question accordingly.

Comment: Referring to Appendix B in *Pseudo-reductive Groups* (2nd ed.) as a published reference, by Prop. B.3.2 if $U$ is not $k$-wound then its cc$kp$-kernel is not $k$-wound. By Prop. B.3.4 there is a unique normal split smooth connected $k$-subgroup $U_s\subset U$ such that $U/U_s$ is $k$-wound. Thus, if $U$ is split and non-trivial then its cc$kp$-kernel $U'$ satisfies $U'_s\ne 1$. Even if $U/U'_s$ has split cc$kp$-kernel by dimension induction (so it is a vector group), it is hard to deduce its wound subgroup $U'/U'_s$ is trivial since wound $k$-groups can embed vector groups. I am baffled.

Comment: In Example K.1.1 of https://www.ams.org/open-math-notes/omn-view-listing?listingId=110663  you'll find an example of a 2-dimensional non-commutative extension $U$ of $\mathbf{G}_a$ by $\mathbf{G}_a$ over $\mathbf{F}_p$ such that the scheme-theoretic center $Z_U$ is equal to $\mathbf{G}_a \times \alpha_p$.  (This *non-commutative* smooth connected $U$ is rather disorienting since its adjoint representation is trivial.) So the identity component of the scheme-theoretic center can fail to be smooth and hence not be "split" according to the definition you are using in the unipotent setting.

Comment: Guys, I was looking at the history of editions of this question and by mistake pushed a button and converted it to its initial version. I then managed to undo the damage and convert it back to its final version again. I hope it is fine now. Sorry!

Comment: Uri, looks like all is fine.